# Especially or specially

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, doubled-words

Please explain the difference between *especially* and *specially* ?

*Especially*:

> ADVERB
>
> 1 Used to single out one person or thing over all others:
>
> 2 To a great extent; very much:

*Specially*:

> ADVERB
>
> For a special purpose:

The definitions make sense on their face, but the way we use the words is confusing. I was reading *The Journal of Henry David Thoreau* today and came across this his of specially that I might have used especially:

> September 7, 1851
>
> We can, perchance, then direct our nutriment to those organs we
>   specially use...
>
> February 23, 1853
>
> The Secretary for the Advancement of Science requests me, ... to fill
>   the blak against certain questions, among which the most important one
>   was what branch of science I was specially interested in ... I felt
>   that it would be to make myself the laughing-stock of the scientific
>   community to describe to them that branch of science that specially
>   interests me...

Is there no difference or one is more prominent than the other?

Comment: What did a dictionary tell you?

Comment: Almost same definition in dictionary but is there any difference if I used one above another or one is more formal?

Comment: Try "The Free Dictionary" online and "Merriam-Webster".  Also, "Oxford Online".  You'll find there is a difference, not only between "special and especial" but also between "specially and especially".

Comment: @Adityaultra To make your question more answerable, you might post the definitions of the words, as well as what confuses you about those definitions. Why do you think they're the same or different?

Comment: These trousers were specially made for soldiers who are fighting in Iraq. They are very comfortable, especially during very hot weather.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62786/what-is-the-difference-between-special-and-especial

Comment: As edited, this question clearly shows research. Voting to reopen.

Comment: This seems to me to be a valid and useful question—and one that is not at all easy to answer. Unless it duplicates a question asked elsewhere on EL&U (which no one has as yet documented), I think it should be open.

Comment: Sed also: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405/specially-vs-especially

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, remember that the way people used words 150 years ago does not **dictate** how we use words today, even though their usage has probably influenced our usage very deeply.

Since *especially* and *specially* look and sound so much alike, it can be very difficult to **realize** the clear differences in their definitions. The fact that *special* and *especial*, their adjectival forms, share even closer definitions makes the confusion that much more difficult to sort out.

From [www.learnersdictionary.com](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/what-s-the-difference-between-specially-and-especially)

> The meanings and usage of these two similar-sounding words overlap
>   quite a bit, so it can be hard to figure out which one to use when. If
>   you are interested in the details, I encourage you to read their
>   entries in Merriam-Webster's Learner’s Dictionary. If that’s more
>   information than you need, here are simple rules to follow that will
>   insure that you are using these words correctly:
>
> 1. Use *especially* to mean “*very*” or “*extremely*,” as in these examples:
>
>    *There is nothing especially radical about that idea.*
>
>    *The food was not especially good.*
> 2. Use *especially* when something stands out from all the others, and you want the meaning of “*particularly*,” as in these examples:
>
>    *She can't be sure she will win, especially at this early stage of
>      the campaign.*
>
>    *The appetizers and especially the soup were
>      delicious.*
> 3. When you want to convey the meaning “*for a special purpose*,” or “*specifically*,” you can use either *especially* or *specially*. They are
>      both correct.
>
>    *The speech was written especially/specially for the
>      occasion.*
> 4. When you want to convey the meaning “*in a special manner*”, as in this example below, use *specially*. In this context, *especially* would
>      sound odd or wrong to most native speakers.
>
>    *I don't want to be treated specially.*
>
>    **[AVOID]** *I don't want to be treated especially.*

Rule 4 is the most important to remember, because it is the only one where *especially* will **not** fit. In all other uses, you can safely assume *especially* will work.

The more extensive difference between the adverbial forms seems to be related to the subtle difference between their [adjectival](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/2special-or-especial) forms:

> The meanings of the adjectives *special* and *especial* are more or
>   less the same. They both mean “*different and more than usual*,” as in
>   the examples below:
>
> *This is a matter of special importance.*
>
> *Pay especial attention to the last paragraph.*
>
> However, *special* is by far more common than *especial*. In fact,
>   according to COCA, the Corpus of Contemporary American English,
>   *special* is used about 600 times for every one time that *especial* is used.
>
> In addition, unlike *especial*, *special* does not need to be followed
>   by a noun, as in this example:
>
> If you’re going to a business lunch, wear something *special*.
>
> Since *special* is much more common, and its use is more flexible, I
>   don’t recommend using *especial* at all.

Since *especial* is fading out of use, you can reduce the confusion by assuming *special* is the right adjective, unless you have a clear compelling reason to use *especial*. Interestingly, the 150:1 usage [ratio](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=special%2C%20especial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspecial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cespecial%3B%2Cc0) of *special* over *especial* is reversed in the 85:1 usage [ratio](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=especially%2C%20specially&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cespecially%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspecially%3B%2Cc0) of *especially* over *specially*. *Especially* is significantly more common than *specially*.

I use the following mnemonic to remember that the adjective *special* is more useful and the adverb *especially* is more popular:

> ***Special* words are *especially* important.**